# CORS Filter is not changing my header

Tags: eclipse, apache, http-headers, servlet-filters, cors

I have a maven project (with web and JPA facets) in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. I have added the jars to my tomcat library and everything compiles great.

**However, my webpage header does NOT reflect what I have enabled in my web.xml through the [CORS filter](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html).**

My header looks like:

[image]

And my web.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<!-- Servlet 1: Expose the OData service endpoint -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>OData</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

<!-- all additional parameters will be passed to your factory create method -->
<init-param>
  <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
  <param-value>org.odata4j.jersey.producer.resources.ODataApplication</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
    <param-name>odata4j.producerfactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.odata4j.producer.jpa.JPAProducerFactory</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
  <param-name>odata4j.jpa.persistenceUnitName</param-name>
  <param-value>Resource</param-value>
</init-param>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>OData</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/example.svc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Servlet 2: Enable crossdomain access for browser clients -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>CrossDomain</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
  <param-value>org.odata4j.producer.resources.RootApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>CrossDomain</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!--  Use CORSFilter for CORS -->
<filter>
<filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
<!-- Note: All parameters are options, if ommitted CORS Filter
   will fall back to the respective default values.
-->
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
<param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
<param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
<param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
<param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
<param-value>Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authentication</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
<param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
<param-value>X-Test-1, X-Test-2</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
<param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
<param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
<param-value>3600</param-value>
</init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you provide request headers ? I think a cross-origin request is not being made here. You can easily identify that by inspecting your request headers and checking for presence of 'Origin' header, which is added by browser, if XMLHttpRequest is made for a different origin.

Comment: Also, Tomcat supports CORS Filter out of box from version 7.0.41, see: [Tomcat CORS Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my headers to support CORS by implementing Padcom's CORS filter for Java application as described [here](http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2011/09/cors-filter-for-java-applications.html).

I'm still not sure why the method I tried above didn't work...
But if you are stuck trying the method above, it is easy and work trying Padcom's method. :)

Comment: solution worked great... but in my case I don't know why I need to define the filter inside web.xmml ... I was thinking that adding @Component annotation of the Filter class was enough but it didn't work. I'll do my reseaarch but in case you know ... please reply, thank you.

Comment: this seems legit : http://jpgmr.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-requests-with-spring-mvc/